# Prove that any minimum vertex cover of a clique of size n must have exactly n-1 vertices

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, clique, vertex-cover

How to prove that any minimum vertex cover of a clique of size n must have exactly n-1 vertices?
THx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is graph theory rather than a concrete programming or implementation question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is should be asked on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort whatsoever, and reeks of homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's two vertices from the clique not in a set, then the edge between them isn't covered, so any cover must have at least n-1 vertices. Any subset of n-1 vertices is a cover, trivially.